# From SQL select sum group by to active record in Yii framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

Below is my pure SQL query.

```
SELECT SUM(money) AS total_money, user_id 
FROM User 
INNER JOIN Person 
        ON Person.user_id = User.user_id 
GROUP BY user_id
```

How can I convert this pure query into ActiveRecord in Yii framework 2? I could solve the `INNER JOIN` but don't know how to solve `SUM` including `GROUP BY` with Yii 2 ActiveRecord

Comment: check out this link - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html

Comment: that link shows how to sum all records. In my case I need to sum and group by. I cannot use: $Model->find()->groupBy('column')->sum('column'); because groupBY will not have effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT` part:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

->select([new Expression('SUM(money) as total_money'), 'user_id'])
```

`GROUP BY` part:

```
->groupBy('user_id')
```

Docs for [select()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#select) and [groupBy()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#group-by) can be found in [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) section.

[yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) is used to prevent quoting.

You can not use [sum()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#sum()-detail) method here because it's aggregation method and returns a number, while in your case you use it with other column to return a set of records.

The whole query will look like this:

```
$personTable = Person::tableName();
$userTable = User::tableName();

$users = User::find()
    ->select([new Expression('SUM(money) as total_money'), 'user_id'])
    ->innerJoin($personTable, "$personTable.user_id = $userTable.user_id")
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->all()
```

A couple more things to mention:

- It's better to use `tableName()` method to get actual table name instead of writing it manually. In this case if you decide to change table name, you only need to change it in one place.
- It's better to replace join part with [relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data).

Comment: can you please make the whole chain? because I miss ->all()

Comment: @OConnor Updated the answer with more info.

Comment: Is it better to do so: $personTable = Person::tableName(); or use Person::tableName() everywhere without assigning value to a variable?

Comment: Assigning to variable is optional, I used separate variables here because concatenation will look worse in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

$atsum =Atttransactions::find()->select([new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(attt_for_receive) as for_receive')])
->addselect([new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(attt_received) as received')])
->where(['attt_attc_id'=>$modelTran->attt_attc_id])
->asArray()->one();